# Convert String to code in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I invoke a java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)
>   [How do I programmatically compile and instantiate a Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class)

I have a function:

```
fun1() {
  System.out.print("hello");
}
```

I want to read a string from either the user or a file, and if the string `"fun1()"` appears, I'd call fun1.

I don't want to do this with a switch statement, because I have a lot of functions.

There is any way to call a function using strings?

Comment: Typically, this is a bad idea.  What are you aiming to accomplish with this?

Comment: I think it would be the same approach as this;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 5):

You *could* use reflection here:

```
Method method = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("fun1", new Class[] {});
method.invoke(this, null);
```

Consider first, however, if you can avoid using reflection then do. Reflection bring with it a number of disadvantages such as being difficult to debug and rendering automatic refactoring tools such as those in Eclipse effectively useless.

Rethink your design; you can probably solve the problem better with cleaner decomposition of classes, better polymorphism, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using reflection. but the method you provided is not java. the return type is missing. why do you want to do this? here is a link, in case you go this route: [invoking a static method using reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467544/invoking-a-static-method-using-reflections)