# Argument type mismatch when invoking method with paramater

Tags: java, swing, reflection

```
Legend legend = ApplicationContext.getLegend();
TreePath[] treePath = getTreePath();
Method method = legend.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getItems", TreePath[].class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(legend, treePath);
```

In Legend.class:

```
private List<LegendItem> getItems(TreePath[] treePath) {
  List<LegendItem> items = new ArrayList();
  if (treepath == null) {
    return items;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < treepath.length; i++) {
    Object[] ob = treepath[i].getPath();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)ob[(treepath[i].getPathCount() - 1)];
  }

  items.add((LegendItem)node.getUserObject());
  return items;
```

}

Why do I get

> Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

when I execute? I defined the parameter to be `TreePath[]` and the parameter I pass is of that type?!

And also following Warning:

> Type TreePath[] of the last argument to method invoke(Object, Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.

for `method.invoke(legend, treePath)`

Solved:

```
method.invoke(legend, new Object[] {treePath});
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Can you post the `Legend.getItems` method's source code?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951521/invoke-method-with-an-array-parameter-using-reflection

Comment: thanks @CptBartendet