# Can I reference method name in Java8?

Tags: java

I have in my code this if

```
if (method.getName().equals("ignore")) {
```

it's pointing to to a static method.

Can I somehow call `getName` on `MyClass::ignore` ??

Comment: What type is `method` in the above? Or is it hypothetical?

Comment: possible duplicate of [invoking a static method using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467544/invoking-a-static-method-using-reflection)

Comment: I sense a possible XY Problem type question here. There's a short answer, and a longer more correct answer that will depend on the background information that we don't know yet til you tell us. In other words, there's likely a much better way to do what you're trying to do than to try to get a method name this way. Please tell us the details of your problem, not how you're trying to solve it, so that we can give accurate help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels method is of type java.lang.reflect.Method. I try not to use hardcoded string value, but method reference. The method is pointing to is checking for is IgnoreLogging.ignore.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I ask abotu new Java8 features!

Comment: @MarounMaroun method is of type java.lang.reflect.Method. I try not to use hardcoded string value, but method reference. The method is pointing to is checking for is IgnoreLogging.ignore.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder method is of type java.lang.reflect.Method. I try not to use hardcoded string value, but method reference. The method is pointing to is checking for is IgnoreLogging.ignore.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no static (compile time) way to reference a method as a `Method` object. You'll have to dynamically retrieve it through [`Class#getMethod(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) (or other appropriate methods). Or use a `String` value for its name as you are currently doing.