# If class exists, call constructor

Tags: java, class, methods, alias

I have this Java code snippet:

```
try {
    Class.forName(command);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {    
}
```

where "command" is a String which is manually entered at runtime. For the sake of the question, let's assume the user enters "Foo".

It checks if there is a class named Foo. The thing I want to do after checking is to call a method from Foo.

```
Foo.execute();
```

How do I do this without making a special "if" case for each of my classes? Is there a way to use something like an alias, ($command).execute() where $command would be (in this case) my Foo Class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467544/invoking-a-static-method-using-reflection

Comment: If you want to reference the classes you can input as a single entity I would say use a super class. So, each class that can be input extends or implements InputClazz.class or something

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at the command Pattern. Just store your Commands in a HashMap<String, Command>. : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077569/core-java/java-tip-68--learn-how-to-implement-the-command-pattern-in-java.html

Comment: Marcinek has the best idea, I'd go that route if possible.  Can you update your question to reflect how much leeway you have implementing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new class from a Variable in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java)

Comment: My advice?  You want JavaScript not Java. Run the JavaScript engine built into the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct would be for any class you want to be able to execute from name would be to make each one implement a common interface.

Example:

```
public Interface InputClazz {
    public void execute();
}

public class Foo implements InputClazz {
  public void execute() {
    //do Stuff
  }
}

public class Bar implements InputClazz {
  public void execute() {
    //do Stuff
  }
}
```

How to invoke:

```
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(command);
    InputClazz input = (InputClazz) clazz.newInstance();
    input.execute();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {    
}
```

You can then input either Foo or Bar and the code will run the concrete execute methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the reflection and the invoke method like this:

```
Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
```

See this tutorial for details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 0):

This prints "Hello World"

```
private static void call(String className, String methodName) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        Method method = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
        method.invoke(instance);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class Foo {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    call(Foo.class.getName(), "foo");
}
```

The only thing not as nice is that you'll have to use the fully qualified class name. So instead of `Foo` it's likely something ugly like `com.mycompany.something.Foo`. Or you really have to make sure those classes are in no package.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nappa has a good, practical answer.  If you want to be a little fancier, you can check your class for membership in a hierarchy with `isAssignableFrom()` on the `Class` method.

The code below uses a built-in hierarchy (`StringBuilder` implements the `CharSequence` interface).  When it finds a class of type `CharSequence`, it casts the class and then calls `length()` on it.

You can maintain control of your class types without throwing exceptions, which might be a little cleaner in some circumstances.

Note that this code still throws `ClassNotFoundExcpetion` if you spell then name of a class incorrectly.  You must still catch that exception.

```
public class ReflectionSubclassing
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
           throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, 
           IllegalAccessException 
   {
      getDoubleValue( "java.lang.StringBuilder" );
      getDoubleValue( "javax.swing.JButton" );
   }

   private static void getDoubleValue( String className ) 
           throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, 
           IllegalAccessException
   {
      Class<?> tempClass = Class.forName( className );
      if( java.lang.CharSequence.class.isAssignableFrom( tempClass ) ) {
         Object charSeq = tempClass.newInstance();
         CharSequence cs = (java.lang.CharSequence)charSeq;
         System.out.println( cs.length() );
      } else
         System.out.println( "nope" );
   }
}
```

Sample code output:

```
run:
0
nope
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```