# Get enum.values() from class that containing it

Tags: java, reflection, enums

```
class Clazz{
    public enum MyEnum{
        Hello, World
    }
}
```

With class `Clazz`, how do I get `MyEnum.values()` ?

An example of the usage is :

```
Class unknownClass = getSomeClass();
```

How to get `MyEnum.values()` from `unknownClass`?

Comment: Hint: inner enums are implicitly static.

Comment: What have you tried? We need to know what you've tried and what's not working

Comment: I was not looking for that. I am sorry that the question is vague, but I really want a reflection type answer. With just the Class Object

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what you want to achieve. Also tag it properly (`reflection` tag could be nice if you need your solution to use it).

Comment: Are you asking how to find all nested subclasses using Reflection?

Comment: Asking how to get the MyEnum.values(), from some generic class Object if it exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `Clazz.MyEnum.values()` to access the `Enum` or you can directly import `MyEnum` in your other classes `import com.in.Clazz.MyEnum` becuase `MyEnum` is `public`.

To get `MyEnum` constant via reflection, but if `MyEnum` is accessible then there is no need to use reflection. You can do it in following way,

```
Class<?> clazz = Clazz.class;//You are getting dynamically
Class<?> enumClass = clazz.getDeclaredClasses()[0];//assuming at index 0
Enum<?>[] enumConstants = (Enum<?>[]) enumClass.getEnumConstants();
System.out.println(enumConstants[0]);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

[The answer is here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467562/4769751)

```
Method method = parameterIDClass.getMethod("values");
Enum<?>[] enums = (Enum<?>[])method.invoke(null);
```