# Calling static method from template in Apache Click

Tags: java, velocity, click-framework

How can I call a static method from a (velocity) template when using Apache Click?

Comment: See also [Calling class methods (static) from inside a velocity view page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329191/calling-class-methods-static-from-inside-a-velocity-view-page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

> addModel("MyClass", MyClass.class)

in your Page.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity 1.6 and up supports this:

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses