# How to use springMessage() within springFormInput in Velocity?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization, velocity

I'm using Spring MVC and Velocity templates for an internationalized website.

On my signup form, I'm using data binding via #springFormInput tags.

How can I set a translated placeholder within it?

It will be something like this:

`#springFormInput("signupForm.emailAddress", "required email='true' maxlength='100' placeholder='TRANSLATED STRING'")`

I thought I could do something like this, but I'm not sure how to nest the methods:

`#springFormInput("signupForm.emailAddress", "required email='true' maxlength='100' placeholder='#springMessage("email_address")'")`

(In this case, "email_address" is the "key" in the messages.properties file of translations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.  I had to set a variable (in Velocity) in the line above.

See the lines with `$placeholderPassword`.

```
#springBind("signupForm.password")
#if("$!status.errorCode" != "")
    #set($passwordError = true)
#end
<div class="input password#if($passwordError) invalid#end">
<div class="icon">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
#set($placeholderPassword = "#springMessage($TranslationConstants.PASSWORD)")
#springFormPasswordInput("signupForm.password", "placeholder='$placeholderPassword'")
<div class="status">
    <div class="image"></div>
    #if($passwordError)
        <div for="password" class="alert alert-error">
            $status.errorMessage
        </div>
    #end
</div>
</div>
```

$TranslationConstants is injected via FieldMethodizer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15126547/470749).

Answer (score 0):

Without using the FieldMethodizer and setting a velocity variable you can do:

```
#springFormInput("saleReportForm.reference" "class=form-control placeholder='#springMessage('saleReportForm.reference.placeholder')'")
```