# Is there any way to cast an object in velocity?

Tags: java, velocity

I am using velocity template to generate some string and passing object type to context.

I wanted to cast that object to specific class is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you would handle such tasks on the Java side, not on the template side.

Nevertheless, if you're not using a SecureUberspector, it's doable (but really hackish...):

```
#set($casted = $someObject.class.forName('target.class.name').cast($sourceObject))
```

Comment: Thank you Claude for the help

Answer (score 2):

Claude Brisson's answer works, but from Velocity 1.6 and upwards, it can be done a little simpler and without using `Class.forName()` which can create dependencies on classes that are invisible at compile time.

Let's say I wanted to cast something to a `String`. In Java:

```
context.put("String", String.class);
```

Then in Velocity I can use:

```
#set($casted = $String.cast($sourceObject))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15126547/3249197)