# how to retrieve the liferay authToken using velocity

Tags: authorization, liferay, velocity

How to I retrieve the authToken for the current page in Liferay Velocity?

For example, in the HTML code there is the following but I do not know what is the coding to retrieve the corresponding value 0H4mKLWq for the auth Token assigned for the current session of the webpage.

The following is the string in the HTML:

```
Liferay.authToken="0H4mKLWq";
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Freemarker](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/68268681) you can do it using static method:

> ```
> <#assign authTokenUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthTokenUtil"] />
> ${authTokenUtil.getToken(request)}
> ```

In [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329191/calling-class-methods-static-from-inside-a-velocity-view-page) you can call static methods by adding `AuthTokenUtil` to context
or loading it using `Class.forName`

```
#set($authTokenUtil=$String.class.forName('com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthTokenUtil'))
```

Comment: I tried the following in my Velocity template to retrieve the authToken of the current session but it doesn't seem to work and the string "$authToken" is used in the href code instead of the value of $authToken in the set statement:

Comment: #set($authTokenUtil = $String.class.forName("com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthTokenUtil"))
#set($authToken = $authTokenUtil.getAuthToken())
<a href="https://www.example.com/news?p_auth=${authToken}>Click</a>

Comment: What should I do in order to retrieve the Liferay.authToken value (which is "0H4mKLWq" in this example as seen in the following towards the end of the following code Liferay.authToken="0H4mKLWq";) for the current HTML session that I can see in the header session of the HTML code like the following:

Comment: <html>
<head> <title>Some Title</title> 
<script type="text/javascript">.....(removed unnecessary text）Liferay.authToken="8Gv0m7IO";Liferay.currentURL="\x2fsubpagename";Liferay.currentURLEncoded="%2Fsubpagename";</script>